# How can I reduce outliers in the output of a regression model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using a Keras model for regression which inputs are sensor measurements, and the output is the attitude of the sensor. This model consists of CuDNNLSTM and CNN. I need to reduce the number or range of outliers in the output.

The mean error is reasonable and low, but there are so many outliers in the output. The mean error is around 1, but as you can see in the boxplot, sometimes I get 180 errors (the maximum possible error).

[image]

The training data has no outlier and has been preprocessed before.

How can I reduce the outliers in the output?
Are there any specific network topologies or layers that could handle this?

I tried normalizing the input or adding gaussian noise, but none of them had any impact on the number of outliers in the outputs. Also, I tried all possible loss functions (more than 38), and this is the best result.

The model is:

```
Acc = Input((window_size, 3), name='acc')
Gyro = Input((window_size, 3), name='gyro')
AGconcat = concatenate([Acc, Gyro], axis=2, name='AGconcat')

fs = Input((1,), name='fs')
ACNN = Conv1D(filters=133,
                kernel_size = 11,
                padding = 'same',
                activation = tfa.activations.mish,
                name= 'ACNN')(Acc)
ACNN = Conv1D(filters=109,
                kernel_size = 11,
                padding = 'same',
                activation = tfa.activations.mish,
                name= 'ACNN1')(ACNN)
ACNN = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3,
                    name = 'MaxPooling1D')(ACNN)
ACNN = Flatten(name='ACNNF')(ACNN)

GCNN = Conv1D(filters=142,
                kernel_size = 11,
                padding = 'same',
                activation = tfa.activations.mish,
                name= 'GCNN')(Gyro)
GCNN = Conv1D(filters=116,
                kernel_size = 11,
                padding = 'same',
                activation = tfa.activations.mish,
                name= 'GCNN1')(GCNN)
GCNN = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3,
                    name = 'GyroMaxPool1D')(GCNN)
GCNN = Flatten(name='GCNNF')(GCNN)

AGconLSTM =Bidirectional(CuDNNGRU(128, return_sequences=True, 
                                    #return_state=True,
                                    go_backwards=True,
                                    name='BiLSTM1'))(AGconcat)
                                    
FlattenAG = Flatten(name='FlattenAG')(AGconLSTM)
AG = concatenate([ACNN, GCNN,FlattenAG])
AG = Dense(units=256,
                activation= tfa.activations.mish)(AG)
Fdense = Dense(units=256,
                activation= tfa.activations.mish,
                name= 'Fdense')(fs)
AG = Flatten(name='AGF')(AG)
x = concatenate([AG, Fdense])
x = Dense(units=256,
                    activation= tfa.activations.mish)(x)
x = Flatten(name='output')(x)
output = Dense(4, activation='linear', name='quat')(x)
```

Comment: Stop reposting the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74694427/outlier-in-neural-networks-output-regression this is not a programming problem and you will not find an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try weight decay and regularization. For the last line, you can add this:

```
quat = Lambda(lambda x: k.l2_normalize(x, axis=1), name='QuatNorm')(quat)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried this, but it does not impact significantly. Also, I tried to add regularization to each layer, but the performance dropped significantly.